# Is there accepted decimal-based Unicode notation for technical audiences?

Tags: language-agnostic, xml, unicode, notation

When writing for technical audiences, there are various ways to type Unicode representations, but they all seem to be Hexadecimal:

- `\uFFFF` - From C# / Java Strings
- `\U0000FFFF` - From C# / Java Strings

However, Unicode can also be specified in decimal, and can be entered both ways in XML Entities:

- Hexadecimal: `&#xFFFF;`
- Decimal: `&#65535;`

While I could just (kind of) use `\u65535`, this does make something that is already defined as specifically hexadecimal and abuse it, and also could cause problems - is `\u1111` decimal or hex?

So - are there any programming languages that allow similar ways to denote Unicode characaters by decimal, or common shorthand conventions for specifying Unicode in decimal notation for technical audiences?

Comment: please don't **[cross-post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info "'Cross-posting is frowned upon...'")**: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29044742/is-there-an-accepted-notation-for-decimal-unicode-values-similar-to-uffff

Comment: What are my options? It's getting closed on SO, I don't see any option to move it to this site, and read the FAQ and thought it belonged here. Am I able to move my questions across sites, and missed it?

Comment: Unicode is designed to place different character sets in particular hexadecimal ranges.  Referring to them with decimal values, while possible, is not the way to go.  It's much easier to remember that Hiragana starts at 0x3040 than 12352.

Comment: Certain uses, like XML Entities and Windows Alt{Numpad Entry} use decimal, and what is 'easy to remember' is subjective. Sometimes there are reasons to specify the decimal value, and I'm wondering if anything already supports the equivalent of `\u` for decimals (yes/no), and if not what a good way to type it when/if a situation arises.

Comment: I think you need to show a good specific case where you'd have a reason to use the decimal form. It's certainly not common form, and I simply don't see a reason for it.

Comment: That is not necessary in order to answer the question. Either some languages/syntaxes/specifications (other than XML Entities) has notation for it, or they do not. Why I'm interested is for manual conversion of XML entities into C# chars without a decimal-to-hex conversion first.

Comment: And the answer for C# is no - the `\u`, `\U` and `\x` escape sequences are hexadecimal only. I'm wondering about other ones.

Comment: It’s unclear what you are asking. “Technical audiences” cannot be expected to know all the possible programming languages, so what would it help (in an unspecified problem) to know that some exotic language has a notation? In a comment, you are saying that the motivation is manual conversion of “XML entities” (apparently, decimal character references), but that’s really a *third* question (and it’s unclear why you would do such things manually).

Comment: I didn't say the language had to be exotic. The reason `\u0020` and `\x34` work well to convey this message is because C# and Java use this syntax, and a quick search on this will make it clear to a technical audience what '\u' or '\x' mean. If, for example, C++ or Scala or Go had something like `\d123`, then this would both answer the question at the bottom (yes) and provide a usable notation for technical audiences, which can be expected to have internet access.

Answer (score 4):

**There is no commonly accepted decimal notation for Unicode codepoints.**

Unicode codepoints are almost universally represented in hexadecimal.  The sole exception I'm aware of is the use of Numeric Character References (NCRs) in languages derived from SGML (*e.g.*, HTML and XML), which can take one of two forms: `&#nnn;` in decimal or `&#xnnn;` in hexadecimal.

In other contexts, some languages have attempted to intermingle differing numeric bases - the best-known example being C's use of `nnn` for decimal, `0nnn` for octal, and `0xnnn` for hexadecimal.  Even with this well-known usage, it trips up beginning C programmers all the time that `012` and `12` are different numbers.

Comment: Thank you. I looked into the more common languages (C#, C, C++, Java) and couldn't find decimal based notation. If indeed there is no language support, is there any notation that would communicate this to you (personally) aside from `&#nnn;` or writing out `the unicode code-point for decimal 123`?

Comment: Why bother?  Instead, fully embrace this rare, near-universal, agreement on notation.

Comment: @Ehryk: You can write `wchar_t(123)` when you mean `U+007B`. But that's a single character, not part of a string.

Comment: I value completeness of features more than agreement on a subset of them, which is why I'm bothering. @MSalters, I suppose `NCHAR(123)` would convey that as well, from MS SQL Server, thanks.

Comment: Well, how many bases would you need for feature completeness? There's one canonical base, and that's hex.

Comment: @MSalters Well, there's always [sexigesimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sexagesimal) :-)

Comment: I didn't say radix completeness, but decimal is in more human usage than any other base; sexigesimal is probably the next most utilized (seconds/minutes/arcseconds/arcminutes), then hex and then binary. Decimal being the most used radix in the entire world is notable. Unicode is listed in many places in both hex and decimal.

Answer (score 0):

So far here are some ways decimal Unicode can be specified enough to convey the meaning to anyone who searches:

- XML Entity Notation: `&#nnn;`
- C / C++ Wide Character: `wchar_t(nnn)`
- SQL National Character: `NCHAR(nnn)` (Available in MSSQL, MySQL, Oracle)
- Windows ALT Notation: `ALT+nnn` (although it can be easily confused with the hex version with the plus key, `ALT++01bd`)

I'm interested in any others to add to this list.